# How do I specify that "bold" should be "Avenir Heavy" not "Avenir Black"?

Tags: html, ios, css, email, fonts

I need to send HTML-formatted email using the Avenir font (if it's present in the OS). Two of this font's weights are Heavy and Black (the latter being the heaviest weight). I want mail clients to use Avenir Heavy for bold text, but they're using Avenir Black instead.

In my HTML I have a `<style type="text/css">` tag with:

```
body {
    font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.font_h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

When I open my HTML file in a desktop browser (Firefox, Chrome, or Safari), it uses Avenir Heavy as the bold font. But when I email it and view it in Mac Outlook 2016 or in iOS 10's Mail client, those display the bold font with Avenir Black, which is a much heavier font. Same thing happens if I specify the `font-weight` as `bolder`.

Oddly, if I say:

```
body {
    font-family: Avenir Heavy;
}
```

then the page is still rendered by desktop browsers with Avenir Medium, with Avenir Heavy used for bold.

I don't think that `@font-face` is my answer, because I'm not loading a font from a URL.

How can I tell the browser or mail client to specifically use Avenir Heavy as the bold weight?

Comment: you could try adding that heavy font to a class name and adding that class name to the elements you want bold

Comment: Either add the `font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;` to your `.font_h1` CSS rule. Or do what @Toxide82 advised and make `font-family: Avenir;` a separate class and add that class to your `.font_h1` element. Don't trust the email client to inherit the `font-family` from the `body` CSS rule, declare it explicitly.

Comment: @Toxide82: In Firefox, I tried specifying `style="font-weight: normal; font-family: Avenir Black;"` directly on an element, but it is rendered as Avenir Medium. Specifying `style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Avenir Black;"` gives me Avenir Heavy.

Comment: @JonathanMarzullo: I think you misunderstood - it does appear to be correctly inheriting the Avenir font-family; it's just not letting me choose a correct weight of Avenir to use for bold.

Comment: why cant you use `style="font-family: Avenir Heavy";`

Comment: Can you specify the font weight as a number like 700 or 800? When i look up that font it has a different font for each weight, with the font sub group only showing `bold`. Unlike other font-families that have all their sub group fonts for font weight being part of the same font-family name.

Comment: @Toxide82: `style="font-family: Avenir Heavy";` displays `font-weight: normal` as Avenir Medium, and `font-weight: bold` as Avenir Heavy or Avenir Black depending on whether it's a browser or an email client. This is how it's working for me, at least.

Comment: @JonathanMarzullo: I'll try using the font weight as a number and see what happens.

Comment: So, get this. In desktop Firefox, font-weight 600 through 800 renders as Avenir Heavy, and 900 renders as Avenir Black (the heaviest weight), which is correct. But in desktop Outlook and mobile Safari, it's the other way around: 600-800 are Avenir Black, and 900 is lighter as Avenir Heavy!

Comment: And add to this that desktop Chrome correctly renders 900 as heavier than 600-800, but desktop Safari also renders them backwards with 900 lighter than 600-800. I don't see any solution other than to figure out CSS for each individual client.

Answer (score 3):

I declare Avenir like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Avenir Book'), local('Avenir-300'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Book/Avenir-Book.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Book/Avenir-Book.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Book/Avenir-Book.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Avenir Medium'), local('Avenir-500'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Medium/Avenir-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Medium/Avenir-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Medium/Avenir-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Avenir Heavy'), local('Avenir-700'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Heavy/Avenir-Heavy.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Heavy/Avenir-Heavy.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Heavy/Avenir-Heavy.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Avenir Black'), local('Avenir-900'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Black/Avenir-Black.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Black/Avenir-Black.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/Avenir-Black/Avenir-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

And then in CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 900; // black
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 700; // heavy
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 500; // medium
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to explicitly open the font (using a font processing app, such as fontforge) and check which family it belongs to. Then use that family name and you'll be home safe. Also, if you want to be precise about your weights, use numbered values such as

- 400 for normal
- 700 for bold
- 900 for black
- etc.